# RelativeLayout in android Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am working at an android app in `Titanium`. I want that my app to have the same look on all phones. I want to use something like `RelativeLayout`, to put a Button on the right/left / below/ part of another Button. How to do this in Titanium?
Until now, my app looks fine on device but on emulator it is not the same, almost every view has a different position.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try setting percentage values for your lay out, hope will work that way

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @Gabrielle: have tried with left: '30dp' ?

Comment: No, I didn't. It works with the answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rajesh is right.
You need to work with percentages.

Like this:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD'
});
var lblDummy = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    text: 'Dummy Text';
    textAlign: 'center',
    top: '50%',
    left: '30%',
    width: '100%',
    height: '10%',
    font: { fontFamily: 'Helvetica', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }
});
win.add( lblDummy );
win.open();
```